# Erlang How to mix try catch with if

Tags: erlang

I'm very new in Erlang. 
I want to make function to check ban word.

But I got syntax errors.. 
How to use try catch with if else statement?

```
check_banword(Word, BlackWord) ->
    try 
      Res = string:rstr(Word, BlackWord),
      if Res > 0 -> 
          true;
      true ->    
          false
    catch
      false
    end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems in the code:

1. Missing `end` after `if`
2. Catch syntax is incorrect, catch matches exceptions to values, you cannot have just a value there.

The code with changes enabling it to compile looks like

```
    check_banword(Word, BlackWord) ->
      try 
        Res = string:rstr(Word, BlackWord),
        if
          Res > 0 -> 
            true;
          true ->    
            false
        end
      catch
        _ -> false
      end.
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't actually need the `if`, you can use `try` with patterns and guards.  When used in this way, `try` looks like a `case` expression with a `catch` section at the end.  (Note that only the part between `try` and `of` is "protected" by the `catch` - in this case, it doesn't make any difference because the rest of the code cannot raise an error.)

Also note that you need to specify what type of exception you want to catch, one of `error`, `exit` and `throw`.  If you don't specify the type of exception, it defaults to `throw` - and that's not what you want here, since `string:rstr` never throws anything, it can only raise errors if the arguments are of an incorrect type.

So that would be:

```
check_banword(Word, BlackWord) ->
  try string:rstr(Word, BlackWord) of
      Res when Res > 0 -> 
        true;
      _ ->    
        false
  catch
    error:_ -> false
  end.
```

---

And there is a wider question: should you actually use `try` here?  If an error occurs in this function, it means that the arguments were not strings, and that is the caller's responsibility.  Since there isn't anything that this function can do to fix the problem, I'd say that it shouldn't catch the error but let it propagate to the caller.  (This is known as Erlang's "let it crash" philosophy.)